# Construct an array of dates between start and end dates. (d3.js)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

For instance, I have `start` and `end`

```
start = new Date(2013, 2, 28)
end   = new Date(2013, 3, 2)
```

How could I get from this an array like this

```
[new Date(2013, 2, 28),
 new Date(2013, 2, 29),
 new Date(2013, 2, 30),
 new Date(2013, 2, 31),
 new Date(2013, 3, 1),
 new Date(2013, 3, 2)]
```

I'm currently reading docs about [Time-Scales](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales) but still having trouble in understanding how to use them for achieving this effect. (Or, maybe there is a better way to do this, if so, I'd be happy to know)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do it with d3:

```
var dateArray = d3.time.scale()
                .domain([new Date(2013, 2, 28), new Date(2013, 3, 2)])
                .ticks(d3.time.days, 1)
```

Online demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aczuV/1/

Answer (score 8):

To update this answer for the [d3 V4 syntax](https://github.com/d3/d3-time/blob/master/README.md#timeDays), use:

```
var dateRange = d3.timeDays(new Date(2013, 2, 28), new Date(2013, 3, 2));
```

Some important notes:

- The month is 0-indexed, so 0 is *January*. This example will start on March 28th, not February 28th.
- The end date is not included in the return value. Thus the last date in the this example is the 1st, not the 2nd.

Comment: Thank you for this; the other answers will produce errors with v4.

Answer (score 4):

Just found out that I can use `range` with [Time Intervals](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Intervals)

```
d3.time.day.range(new Date(2013, 2, 28),
                  new Date(2013, 3, 2 + 1))
```

Comment: I forgot about that! Even shorter: d3.time.days(new Date(2013, 2, 28), new Date(2013, 3, 2))