# Interpolating dates between start/end dates: Best to do in Django's view or D3?

Tags: python, django, pandas, d3.js

I am new to D3 and am trying to build a stacked date series plot with around 10 elements. Initially I will *linearly* distribute the costs over each time period (however, other distributions would be nice to consider in the future). My goal is to have pages which display time-series plots with use either all series' or just a subset.

My Django model has the parameters of each stored in the (SQLite) database like this:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    #... 
    S1_start=models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True)
    S1_end=models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True)
    S1_cost=models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    #S2_start ...
```

From what I've been reading, I can see two possible ways as detailed below. My thinking is that the Pandas DataFrame gives me more flexibility but I don't know whether repeated pickling/unpickling is going to be an unacceptable bottleneck. Any guidance gratefully received!

For each of these `S` groups:

## Interpolate to static Panda Dataframe (all series' on each database update)

1. When any updates are made to a `Project` entity, create elements for each date (`date_range()`) and spread each cost over it's duration
2. Store each `S` in a Pandas DataFrame and pickle it to a static file
3. On requests to a graphic's URL, unpickle the DataFrame and send over the required elements (as JSON array?)

## Interpolate with D3 (only the series' required for plot)

1. When any updates are made to a `Project` entity, just save the three parameters for each `S` (`start`,`end`,`cost`) back to the database
2. On requests to a graphic's URL, send these same data over and have [D3 interpolate the date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246002/construct-an-array-of-dates-between-start-and-end-dates-d3-js).

In D3, something like:

```
d3.json("{% url "visualAPI" studyCode=project.project_code %}", 
    function(d) {
        d.costs = +d.S1_costs;
        d.dateRange = d3.time.scale()
            .domain([parseDate(d.S1_start), parseDate(d.S1_end)])
            .ticks(d3.time.days, 1);
      });
```